# Error: Undefined control sequence with \bdfn

Tags: packages, compilation-error

I'm just starting with Latex and I'm getting this error:

[image]

is there any library missing?

Comment: (1) welcome, (2) sorry but how should we know from just an image? Where did you define `\bdfn`? Generally we need code

Comment: this looks like some home made shortcut for \begin{definition}  \end{definition}. Such shortcuts are normally not a good idea.

Comment: Unrelated: probably not a good idea to use `\underbrace` in the running text as it will disturb the line spacing. Only use that in displayed formulas.

Comment: woh, so quickly. Hum... I'm gonna try to look at that shortcut again (I'm writing the paper with more people and sometimes it's complicated to understand). If I don't succeed, I'll try to explain myself better.Thanks y'all!

Comment: Basically tell your co-authors that `\bdfn ... \edfn` makes that code very very hard to read compared to `\begin{definition} ... \end{definition}` and for that reason such shortcuts are not recommended especially in documents with multiple authors working on it.